# Can MySQL log lock waits?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Is it possible to have MySQL log queries or transactions where lock waits occur? One can debug specific application errors generated from lock wait timeout errors from the DB but without the ability to become aware of the occurrences of lock waits that *don't* hit the timeout, it seems difficult to anticipate where the next timeout error may be lurking.

Is there a way to have MySQL log these?

Comment: If you were on 5.6, I'd post this as an answer, but if you could upgrade to 5.6 (good to see that some people mention versions around here), then you could have a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-waits-summary-tables.html). The P_S is a marvellous thing - I can't wait for it to be as mature as Oracle's Wait Interface. Table lock tracking doesn't appear to be available in 5.5.

Comment: We will likely be going to 5.6 shortly so feel free to post this as an answer - could be valuable to others too. Though seems like it tells you which tables have lock contention but not which queries were waiting right?

Comment: I'll have to look into this tomorrow - I seem to have read stuff about this, but can't lay my hands on the URLs - the good thing about all of this work is that nobody has written any books about it yet - it's just all in the docco or on the interweb.

Comment: @Vérace any further thoughts on this? Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 2):

I have some good news and some bad news.

The good news is that this will work for MySQL. The 
bad news is that it won't work for 5.5. In any case,
I would advise moving to 5.6 anyway, in no small part
due to the vast improvements made to the performance
schema (see below).

I compiled and installed 5.6 (am currently running
5.7 - bit of a bleeding edge type of guy :-) ).

After some frustrating Googling &c. and barking
up a forest of wrong trees, I finally came up
with this.

```
SELECT Table_schema, Table_Name, Column_Name 
FROM Information_Schema.Columns 
Where (Table_Schema = 'information_schema'
or Table_Schema = 'sys') 
AND Column_Name like '%lock%';
```

But, if you check Result 1 (at end of post), you'll 
see I didn't have much luck.

But then I remembered Mark Leith's (Software 
Development Senior Manager, Oracle) MySQL
sys schema (and ps_helper). These are available
from here

https://github.com/MarkLeith.

I ran the same SQL as above with

or Table_Schema = 'sys'

added, and I came up with Result 2 (at end
of post).

Innodb_Wait_Locks looked promising, so I ran a DESC.

```
mysql> DESC sys.innodb_lock_waits;
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| waiting_trx_id      | varchar(18)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| waiting_thread      | bigint(21) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| waiting_query       | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| waiting_lock_id     | varchar(81)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| waiting_lock_mode   | varchar(32)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| waiting_lock_type   | varchar(32)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| waiting_lock_table  | varchar(1024)       | NO   |     |         |       |
| waiting_lock_index  | varchar(1024)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| blocking_trx_id     | varchar(18)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| blocking_thread     | bigint(21) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| blocking_query      | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| blocking_lock_id    | varchar(81)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| blocking_lock_mode  | varchar(32)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| blocking_lock_type  | varchar(32)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| blocking_lock_table | varchar(1024)       | NO   |     |         |       |
| blocking_lock_index | varchar(1024)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, there you have pretty much all the info you could 
want about locks, (I hope!).

No, as to logging these, there doesn't appear to be a logging function
for this table - many of the p_s tables have accompanying history
tables. I think that there's a good case for keeping a history of
this one - but you can "roll your own" using MySQL events to
append the contents of this table to a logging table.

Say every one second (or period of your choice) and then check to
see which of your queries are regularlary appearing in the
logging table. It's perhaps not up to Oracle's functionality,
but it's getting there :-)

**Result 1**

```
+--------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+
| Table_schema       | Table_Name             | Column_Name                |
+--------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+
| information_schema | PROFILING              | BLOCK_OPS_IN               |
| information_schema | PROFILING              | BLOCK_OPS_OUT              |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS           | lock_id                    |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS           | lock_trx_id                |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS           | lock_mode                  |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS           | lock_type                  |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS           | lock_table                 |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS           | lock_index                 |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS           | lock_space                 |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS           | lock_page                  |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS           | lock_rec                   |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS           | lock_data                  |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX             | trx_requested_lock_id      |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX             | trx_tables_locked          |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX             | trx_lock_structs           |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX             | trx_lock_memory_bytes      |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX             | trx_rows_locked            |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX             | trx_autocommit_non_locking |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCK_WAITS      | requested_lock_id          |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCK_WAITS      | blocking_trx_id            |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCK_WAITS      | blocking_lock_id           |
| information_schema | INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU | FREE_PAGE_CLOCK            |
| information_schema | INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE     | BLOCK_ID                   |
| information_schema | INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE     | FREE_PAGE_CLOCK            |
+--------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+
24 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

**Result 2**

```
+--------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Table_schema       | Table_Name                          | Column_Name                |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| information_schema | PROFILING                           | BLOCK_OPS_IN               |
| information_schema | PROFILING                           | BLOCK_OPS_OUT              |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS                        | lock_id                    |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS                        | lock_trx_id                |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS                        | lock_mode                  |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS                        | lock_type                  |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS                        | lock_table                 |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS                        | lock_index                 |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS                        | lock_space                 |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS                        | lock_page                  |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS                        | lock_rec                   |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCKS                        | lock_data                  |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX                          | trx_requested_lock_id      |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX                          | trx_tables_locked          |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX                          | trx_lock_structs           |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX                          | trx_lock_memory_bytes      |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX                          | trx_rows_locked            |
| information_schema | INNODB_TRX                          | trx_autocommit_non_locking |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCK_WAITS                   | requested_lock_id          |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCK_WAITS                   | blocking_trx_id            |
| information_schema | INNODB_LOCK_WAITS                   | blocking_lock_id           |
| information_schema | INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU              | FREE_PAGE_CLOCK            |
| information_schema | INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE                  | BLOCK_ID                   |
| information_schema | INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE                  | FREE_PAGE_CLOCK            |
| sys                | host_summary_by_statement_latency   | lock_latency               |
| sys                | host_summary_by_statement_type      | lock_latency               |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | waiting_lock_id            |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | waiting_lock_mode          |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | waiting_lock_type          |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | waiting_lock_table         |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | waiting_lock_index         |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | blocking_trx_id            |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | blocking_thread            |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | blocking_query             |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | blocking_lock_id           |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | blocking_lock_mode         |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | blocking_lock_type         |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | blocking_lock_table        |
| sys                | innodb_lock_waits                   | blocking_lock_index        |
| sys                | processlist                         | lock_latency               |
| sys                | statement_analysis                  | lock_latency               |
| sys                | user_summary_by_statement_latency   | lock_latency               |
| sys                | user_summary_by_statement_type      | lock_latency               |
| sys                | x$host_summary_by_statement_latency | lock_latency               |
| sys                | x$host_summary_by_statement_type    | lock_latency               |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | waiting_lock_id            |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | waiting_lock_mode          |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | waiting_lock_type          |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | waiting_lock_table         |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | waiting_lock_index         |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | blocking_trx_id            |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | blocking_thread            |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | blocking_query             |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | blocking_lock_id           |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | blocking_lock_mode         |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | blocking_lock_type         |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | blocking_lock_table        |
| sys                | x$innodb_lock_waits                 | blocking_lock_index        |
| sys                | x$processlist                       | lock_latency               |
| sys                | x$statement_analysis                | lock_latency               |
| sys                | x$user_summary_by_statement_latency | lock_latency               |
| sys                | x$user_summary_by_statement_type    | lock_latency               |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
62 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```